# Very complicated first order linear ODE integral

Tags: integration

$$ (x^2+1)y'+3x^3y=6xe^{\frac{-3}{2}x^2}$$

Dividing every thing through gives:

$$y'+ \frac{3x^3}{x^2+1}y=\frac{6xe^{\frac{-3}{2}x^2}}{1+x^2}$$

Now calculating the integrating factor:

$$ u(x)= e^{\int P(x)}$$ $P(x)= \frac{3x^3}{x^2+1}$

U-substitution with back substitution:

$$\int P(x) = \int \frac{u -1}{u}$$

$$\int \frac{u}{u} - \int \frac{1}{u}$$

$$e^{(\frac{3}{2})x^2+1 - ln \vert x^2+1 \vert}$$

Since we have subtraction lets break this up:

$$\frac{e^{\frac{3}{2}x^2+1}}{e^{-ln \vert x^2+1 \vert}}$$

which turns into:

$$(x^2+1)e^{\frac{3}{2}x^2+1}$$

Now finally setting up the general solution:

$$\frac{1}{(x^2+1)e^{\frac{3}{2}x^2+1}}\int (x^2+1)e^{\frac{3}{2}x^2+1}6xe^{\frac{-3}{2}x^2}$$

obviously adding the powers of $e$ gives:

$$\frac{1}{(x^2+1)e^{\frac{3}{2}x^2+1}} \int (6x^3+6x)e^1$$

We will pull $6e$ out:

$$\frac{6e}{(x^2+1)e^{\frac{3}{2}x^2+1}} \int x^3+x$$

$$(\frac{1}{4}x^4 + \frac{1}{2}x^2+c)(\frac{6e}{(x^2+1)e^{\frac{3}{2}x^2+1}})$$

Am I on the right track? Are there any shortucts?

Comment: I think double check your calculation of $e^{\int \frac{3x^3}{x^2+1}\, dx}$. [This](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Exp%28Integral+%283x%5E3%29%2F%28x%5E2+%2B1%29%29) is what WolframAlpha says it is. What did you use for your $u$-substitution? Also your integral for your general solution doesn't look right. We need to multiply the right-hand side of *the ODE that has $1$ as coefficient of $y'$* by the integrating factor. It looks like you multiplied the right-hand side of the original ODE by the integrating factor instead, which is not right.

Comment: i used $u=x^2+1$ I got some of the answer from symbolab with the integration they u sub with back sub

Comment: so you get u in the denominator and u-1 in the numerator

Comment: If $u=x^2+1$, then $x=(u-1)^{1/2}$ and $dx = \frac{1}{2}(u-1)^{-1/2}$. So $\int \frac{3x^3}{x^2+1}\, dx $ would become $$\int \frac{3(u-1)^{3/2}}{u}\cdot \frac{1}{2}(u-1)^{-1/2}\, du  = \color{blue}{\frac{3}{2}}\int \frac{u-1}{u}\, du.$$ It seems like in your calculation, you didn't apply the $\color{blue}{\frac{3}{2}}$ to the whole integral, but only to the $x^2$ part of the answer, which is not right.

Comment: oh man I got to start over

Comment: @K.Gibson: Were you able to finish this problem? Would it be beneficial for me to post a complete answer?